# Matrix fields don't load!

Tags: templating, matrix, frontend, elementquery

I have some matrix fields defined:

[image]

But when I use the matrix blocks inside of an entry - I don't get all blocks - just the richText ones.

I tested it out - just the richtText Matrix blocks will be loaded when I do:

```
  {% include "_private/partials/matrix" with {blocks: entry.bodyContent.all()} %}
```

Is there something I am missing, or is this a bug?

Would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code of your template `_private/partials/matrix` it's not easy to help you.

Maybe you need to check the block type first.
I usually do that with a switch and have a different partial for each block.

So your template `_private/partials/matrix` could look something like this:

```
{% for block in blocks %}
  {% switch block.type %}
    {% case "richText" %}
      {% include "_private/partials/richtext" %}
    {% case "quote" %}
      {% include "_private/partials/qoute" %}
    {% case "image" %}
      {% include "_private/partials/image" %}
    {% case "embed" %}
      {% include "_private/partials/embed" %}
    {% default %}
  {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

The quote partial could look something like this

```
{# do something with block.style #}
<h4>{{block.quote}}</h4>
<h5>{{block.attribution}}</h5>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. The problem is, there are just the Matrix objects with the type of 'richText' the rest ist not even fetched.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
{% include "_private/partials/matrix" with {blocks: entry.bodyContent.typeId(null).all()} %}
```

This fetches all Matrixobjects from any type.
So it works now.

But I don't undestand, why this is necessary.
Maybe its because I used for my first project [this Blogstarter](https://github.com/craftcms/starter-blog#:%7E:text=Craft%20CMS%20Blog%20Starter,with%20the%20Twig%20templating%20language.).

Maybe there are some relicts from craft2 inside.

So I have the solution to my problem - but it would be nice to know why this was necessary.